# mysqli alter table issue

Tags: php, mysqli, alter-table

This is what I have:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {

    $newAward = new AwardCenter($mysqli);
    $arrColumns = array("name", "description", "imageurl", "imagewidth", "imageheight", "autodays", "autorecruits", "category", "subcategory", "ghosts", "advancedwarfare", "blackops3");
    $arrValues = array($_POST['newawardname1'], $_POST['description1'], $_POST['imageurl1'], $_POST['imagewidth1'], $_POST['imageheight1'], $_POST['autodays1'], $_POST['autorecruits1'], $_POST['category1'], $_POST['subcategory1'], $_POST['ghosts1'], $_POST['advancedwarfare1'], $_POST['blackops31'],);

    if($newAward->addNew($arrColumns, $arrValues)) {

    $newAwardInfo = $newAward->get_info_filtered();

        $result = $mysqli->query("ALTER TABLE ".$dbprefix."clanawards_members ADD '".$newAwardInfo['name']."' INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'");
    echo "
        <div style='display: none' id='successBox'>
            <p align='center'>
                Successfully Added New Award: <b>".$newAwardInfo['name']."</b>!
            </p>
        </div>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            popupDialog('Award Center: Location', '".$MAIN_ROOT."members/console.php?cID=".$cID."', 'successBox');
        </script>
    ";

    }
}
```

The issue is that the alter table is not executing at all.
the add new command works

Comment: You probably need a space before the prefix variable

Comment: prefix variable? which one?

Comment: Was looking for Java, found PHP. |-)

Comment: "ALTER TABLE ".$dbprefix." clan ...

Comment: same result. nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clearly a issue with space. Your query should look like

```
"ALTER TABLE ".$dbprefix.".clanawards_members ADD ".$newAwardInfo['name']." INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'"
```

Comment: query is fine now and still doesn't run the alter.

Comment: Well, try the posted modified query in answer. Other than that, I dont see your are executing the query at all.

Comment: took the ' off the variable and it works. didn't see that at first.